# Unable to mount XFS file system (Google compute engine)

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I tried to mount a XFS device, I got the following error

```
$ sudo mount -t xfs -o noatime,noexec,nodiratime /dev/vg0/data /data/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'
```

So I tried to check if XFS was loaded,and I got the following error

```
$ sudo lsmod
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1567 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to load the xfs module manually, and I got the following error

```
$ sudo modprobe xfs
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.3.8-gcg-201305291443/modules.dep.bin'
```

Could someone please tell if am i doing something wrong with mounting an XFS device in GCE. Is XFS supported by GCE in the 1st place? Also the modprobe error is it a bug? if its not, how can i load modules like ip_conntrack ?

OS Image : debian-7-wheezy-v20130723

Kernel version : gce-v20130603 (3.3.8-gcg-201305291443)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that XFS *is* supported.

I was able to mount using:

```
sudo mount -t xfs -o rw,noatime,inode64,allocsize=16m  /dev/sdb1 /storage
```

[Google reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks)

Answer (score 0):

Looks that there is no support for XFS. Google does not allow dynamic module loading.
I have heard while that Google will give developers a possibility to build own kernels...